# Why the height of bottom app bar grow significantly when displaying content edge-to-edge?

Tags: java, android

I want to let user enjoy full screen experience.

I am following guideline from https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge

However, when I apply `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);`, the height of bottom app bar grows significantly.

The picture on the left is before applying `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);`, and the picture on the right is after applying `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);`.

[image]

I am using the following components to implement bottom app bar.

1. `BottomAppBar` (So that `FloatingActionButton` can position in center)
2. `FloatingActionButton`
3. `BottomNavigationView` (So that I can integrate with `NavController` and `NavigationUI`).

This is my layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_content_and_background_image_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_content_linear_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                app:elevation="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <fragment

                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:backgroundTint="#ff0000"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="0dp"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"

            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:itemBackground="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I was wondering, why the height of bottom app bar grow significantly when displaying content edge-to-edge, and how we can avoid such?

Here's the minimal workable example to try out such an issue - https://github.com/yccheok/bottom-navigation-example/tree/4494860eba7959ab59bb5ac2497302473ca0ad85

Comment: Try and add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `bottomappbar.BottomAppBar` attributes, to see if that improves the layout.

Comment: `BottomAppBar(modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp).fillMaxWidth())` 
*Set the height to a fixed value*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

Adding this padding to the `BottomAppBar` is a kind of weird whenever the `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` API is used to have an edge-to-edge app.

The system could automatically add this padding as a way to avoid the overlap between the  `BottomAppBar` buttons and the system bottom navigation bar. Normally this overlapping should happen when using `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` API, because the developer intentionally needs that edge-to-edge; and [that overlap case already handled by the documentation using the insets API](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge#handle-overlaps).

---

**Solution**

When using `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` API, the system still continues to automatically add the padding to the `BottomAppBar` thinking that the `BottomAppBar`is still on top of the assigned room of the system navigation bar (before having edge-to-edge screen). This padding equals to the height of the system bottom navigation bar to ensure that `BottomAppBar` is drawn on top of the system bar without overlap.

To get the exact height of the bottom navigation bar, we can use the window  insets API by registering `View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener`, and get the bottom insets:

The system navigation bar height which equals to the bottom insets needs to be subtracted from the bottom padding of the window `DecorView` view:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(getWindow().getDecorView(), (v, insets) -> {

    Insets systemInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());

    v.setPadding(v.getPaddingLeft(),
            v.getPaddingTop(),
            v.getPaddingRight(),
            v.getPaddingBottom() - systemInsets.bottom); // subtract the insets from the bottom padding
    return insets;
});
```

Now the `BottomAppBar` looks like:

[image]

---

**Original Assumption**

Disclaimer

> This is just left so it probably can help future visitors in another context; but the above solution should be considers instead for the question asked here.

By the following documentation quotes about consuming the insets listener:

[First for the `WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsCompat#CONSUMED()):

> This can be used during insets dispatch in the view hierarchy by
> returning this value from View.onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets) or
> onApplyWindowInsets to stop dispatch the insets to its children to
> avoid traversing the entire view hierarchy.

[Second in the code snippet comment](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge#system-bars-insets):

> ```
> // Return CONSUMED if you don't want want the window insets to keep being 
> // passed down to descendant views.
> return WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED;
> ```

So, probably when using `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` API, the window insets keep passing down to descendant views. Hence, trying to consume that on the Window `DecorView` has been actually solved the problem:

```
// This snippet is used in `onCreate()` method.
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(getWindow().getDecorView(), (v, insets) -> {
    return ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(v, WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED);
    //  return WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED; // Also can be used
});
```

[image]

**Side note:** This could have some overlapping issues for the users that prefer to use the three-button navigation that probably need to be handled:

[image]

Comment: The answer has been edited for better approach